Why do I get a syntax error when I try to swap two rows of the same table?
section table:
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS section (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT (255) NOT NULL, image TEXT (20) NOT NULL)");

I want to swap two rows of the same table in my SQLite database:
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL( "UPDATE section as s1 inner join section as s2 on (s1.id, s2.id) in (("+fromPosition+","+toPosition+"),("+toPosition+","+fromPosition+")) set s1.title=s2.title, s1.image=s2.image");

Error:

SQLiteException: near "as": syntax error (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE section as s1 inner join section as s2 on (s1.id, s2.id) in ((6,7),(7,6)) set s1.title=s2.title, s1.image=s2.image, (OS error - 0:Success)


I dont't really understand what you want to do. Is this the expected change in your table? If not, what else? https://dbfiddle.uk/f9YfevRJ

If the assumption is my previous comment is correct, you can simply run separate updates as shown here: https://dbfiddle.uk/oRPc5b8i. So I await your clarification. Why do you want to switch id's at all? They are the primary key in your table, you usually never change their values.

See https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html for the accepted UPDATE syntax

When attempting to flip rows, as this seems alike, this might require a sub-query; just run two queries, which at first set one ID far ahead of the auto-increment value and swap in two turns.The query as you have it might otherwise never succeed, because the ID is commonly UNIQUE.
Usually this is nothing to worry about, because of SELECT + ORDER BY.

The error is because the syntax of UPDATE, which is (simplified):-
UPDATE the_one_and_only_table_to_be_updated
SET the column(s) to be assigned and the value to be assigned with a , separating columns
FROM  which may be a JOIN clause
WHERE

note that only android U or greater will use a version of SQLite that supports the FROM clause (requires SQlite 3.33.0 or greater).

i.e. SET MUST be before the FROM clause.


Perhaps consider the following which uses CTE's (which would work on a much larger range of android versions):-
WITH
    /* CTE for the to and from values so only need the two instances of parameter binding */
    v(f,t) AS (SELECT 3 /*would be ? for bind*/,5 /* would be the 2nd ?*/),
    /* Get the 2 rows for the swap as the 2nd CTE that drives the actual UPDATE */
    s1 AS (
        SELECT f.id AS fid, f.title AS ftitle, f.image AS fimage, t.id AS tid, t.title AS ttitle, t.image AS timage 
        FROM section AS f  JOIN section AS t ON t.id IN(SELECT t FROM v) WHERE f.id IN(SELECT f FROM v)
        UNION 
        SELECT f.id AS fid, f.title AS ftitle, f.image AS fimage, t.id AS tid, t.title AS ttitle, t.image AS timage 
        FROM section AS f  JOIN section AS t ON f.id IN(SELECT t FROM v) WHERE t.id IN(SELECT f FROM v)

    )
    /* Can now do the UPDATE itself WITH the s1 CTE */
UPDATE section 
    SET 
        title=(SELECT ttitle FROM s1 WHERE s1.fid=section.id ),
        image=(SELECT timage FROM s1 WHERE s1.fid=section.id)
    /* FROM would be here*/ 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT fid FROM s1)
;


note that the values 3 and 5 are hard coded BUT should be replaced with ?'s (the recommended way) and bound or replaced with ...."+fromPosition+","+toPosition+".... (open to SQL injection and thus not recommended)
it should also be noted that the SQL is deliberately a little long-winded to try to explain the code

The following demonstrates the SQL and can be dropped into an SQLite tool:-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS section;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS section (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT (255) NOT NULL, image TEXT (20) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO section(title,image) VALUES ('AT','AI'),('BT','BI'),('CT','CI'),('DT','DI'),('ET','EI'),('FT','FI');
/*Output the table as when loaded with data*/
SELECT * FROM section;

/* Demonstrate the data selected by the s1 CTE i.e. drives a SELECT rather than an UPDATE */
WITH
    v(f,t) AS (SELECT 3,5),
    s1 AS (
        SELECT f.id AS fid, f.title AS ftitle, f.image AS fimage, t.id AS tid, t.title AS tttitle, t.image AS timage 
        FROM section AS f  JOIN section AS t ON t.id IN(SELECT t FROM v) WHERE f.id IN(SELECT f FROM v)
        UNION 
        SELECT f.id AS fid, f.title AS ftitle, f.image AS fimage, t.id AS tid, t.title AS tttitle, t.image AS timage 
        FROM section AS f  JOIN section AS t ON f.id IN(SELECT t FROM v) WHERE t.id IN(SELECT f FROM v)

    )
SELECT * FROM s1
;
/* The UPDATE itself as driven bt the CTE*/
WITH
    /* CTE for the to and from values so only need the two instances of parameter binding */
    v(f,t) AS (SELECT 3 /*would be ? for bind*/,5 /* would be the 2nd ?*/),
    /* Get the 2 rows for the swap as the 2nd CTE that drives the actual UPDATE */
    s1 AS (
        SELECT f.id AS fid, f.title AS ftitle, f.image AS fimage, t.id AS tid, t.title AS ttitle, t.image AS timage 
        FROM section AS f  JOIN section AS t ON t.id IN(SELECT t FROM v) WHERE f.id IN(SELECT f FROM v)
        UNION 
        SELECT f.id AS fid, f.title AS ftitle, f.image AS fimage, t.id AS tid, t.title AS ttitle, t.image AS timage 
        FROM section AS f  JOIN section AS t ON f.id IN(SELECT t FROM v) WHERE t.id IN(SELECT f FROM v)

    )
    /* Can now do the UPDATE itself WITH the s1 CTE */
UPDATE section 
    SET 
        title=(SELECT ttitle FROM s1 WHERE s1.fid=section.id ),
        image=(SELECT timage FROM s1 WHERE s1.fid=section.id)
    /* FROM would be here*/ 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT fid FROM s1)
;
/* Show the table after the updated */
SELECT * FROM section;
/* cleanup the demo environment*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS section;

Running the above results in:-




i.e. the data to drive the updates




i.e. id 3 and 5 have been updated accordingly



